# Setting up Amazon Web Services to Stream Books Only

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services

I want to get started with amazon web services simply to stream books searched for through a custom web site not yet deployed.  So I want to create a free account, but I see they have all these other services like cloud, etc. that they may try to rope you in... I just want to use the web service, is there a test web service for applications currently running on localhost, that will only use the web service portion?  Or do I create the account and provide no current business info?  Or how does this work?

I guess my confusion is also that Amazon offers so many services, and I don't understand what each of them is for too... and what I should be looking at.

Thanks.

Comment: you just want to use `the web service`. That's eceptionally vague. Which one? EC2? S3? SDB? MapReduce? they are all webservices.

Comment: I don't understand what all the services is, so I guess I should append my question to ask: what are they all for? - which leads to some vagueness in my question.

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/products/ more than aptly introduces them, IMHO. I suggest you look no further than EC2 and S3 for the moment (from the description of your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just create an account. There is *no current business info to provide*.

Yeah, you need a credit card.

**However, nothing ever gets charged, unless** you actually use one of these services. In my experience these are all extremely cheap to try out and get started with (see [AWS Simple Monthly Calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html))

*You probably just want to use S3 (for serving static files - with the option of torrenting t
hem (!)) or EC2 (for temporary (auto) scalable webservers machine instances*

Comment: That's storage, I don't want storage, I just want to communicate with their web service...  I want to build an app on a separate server.

Comment: @Brian: you take over ten days to respond, and evidently read only half of the answer? EC2 is not storage. Not as I'm very well running and compiling my tests on them, Solaris, CentOS and Ubuntu all nicely. Oh they have Windows too, should you be interested

Comment: Oh, you can run **[Eucalyptus](http://open.eucalyptus.com)** locally if you want to heavy-duty test cloud instances before going commercial/public with them. However, since you seem to have not got a lot of experience with AWS yet, I'd think this is putting cart before the horse; In general it is far easier to learn it on AWS and subsequently implement your own cloud locally. Once you do, you will be able to use the same images locally as in the cloud, and Eucalyptus has a mgmt API that is 100% (99%?) compatible with Amazons ec2 api

Comment: I didn't realize there was a time limit on responses... OK, thanks for the update.